# How to add state to a function in Rust

Tags: rust, closures

Rust have anonymous closures with state. Can I do the same with named function?

(invalid pseudocode)

```
fn counting_function()->i32 {
  let mut static counter = 0;
  counter = counter + 1;
  return counter.clone();
}
```

I understand I can use structs and functions/traits to do this. And I understand that iterators are the proper way to do it. But leaving aside structs with traits and iterators, can I do this without passing the any burden (of initializing structure) to caller?

Comment: Is calling `Foo::new()` really a burden? You [can have a `static mut`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2face33302089b6afb0fd966dc76753a) in Rust, but this is not thread-safe, so it's usually not a good idea.

Comment: It's not a burden. I learn Rust, and I'm curious how to implement this. It's not like I'll do it in real code.

Answer (score 2):

This is a thread safe variant using an atomic:

```rust
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicUsize, Ordering};

fn counting_function() -> usize {
    static COUNTER: AtomicUsize = AtomicUsize::new(0);
    let result = COUNTER.fetch_add(1, Ordering::Relaxed);
    result
}
```

But it's actually a code smell I'd say.

Answer (score -2):

Your pseudocode almost works as is. To work with the `static mut` variable, you'll need to mark the accessing and modifying parts of your code as `unsafe` as these operations are not threadsafe.

```
fn counting_function() -> u32 {
    static mut counter: u32 = 0;
    let retval = unsafe { counter };
    unsafe {
        counter += 1;
    }
    retval
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's better to mark `counting_function` unsafe in this case instead of using usafe inside the function as this function violates Rust's safety guarantees, so this should be visible to the callers of the function, along with an explaining comment under what circumstances it's safe to use the function.